# Hibernate concat function/operator let other functions translate to concat operators

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm somewhat new to Hibernate and could't find a reason for this problem.

Here's my HQL:

```
update MyEntity set field1 = :value1 || substr(field1, :pos, 100) where ...
```

This translates to:

```
update MY_TABLE set field1=(?||substr(field1||?||100) where ...
```

So, my guess is every comma(`,`) is translated to concat operator(`||`) inside an overlapped parenthesis. Am I missing something?

Comment: What database dialect are you using?

Comment: I found only H2 dialect has the problem. Oracle and Mysql5 are ok. Should I report this as a bug? Where?

Comment: If you are sure it's a bug, I think it's Hibernate one.